# ASP.Net GridView unsorted afrer PostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, postback

I have a custom GridView in asp.net Page. In PageLoad data will be bound to the grid.

```
protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   InitDisplayMode(sender);
}

private void InitDisplayMode(Object sender)
{
   pnlDetails.Visible = SafetyKeyId != -1;
   if (!Page.IsPostBack) 
   {
      BindValues();
   }
   // some other stuff
}

private void BindValues()
{
     MyStrongTypedDataTable tbl = new BusinessObject.GetData();
     dataGrid.DataSource = tbl;
     dataGrid.DataBind();
}
```

Grid View Makrup

```
    <asp:GridView ID="dataGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCreated="OnRowCreated"
              AllowSorting="true" BorderWidth="0" CellPadding="2" CssClass="subitem w100p"
              AllowPaging="true" PageSize="25" RowStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false"
              OnPageIndexChanging="PageGrid" OnRowDataBound="dataGrid_RowDataBound" PagerSettings-Mode="Numeric"
              PagerSettings-Position="Bottom" OnSorting="SortGrid" OnRowDeleting="RowDeleting">
    <RowStyle CssClass="itemRowStyle"/>
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alternatingItemRowStyle"/>
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="headerRowStyle"/>
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="itemFieldStyle" HeaderStyle-CssClass="headerFieldStyle">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkDetail" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="lnkDetail" ImageUrl='<%# "~/App_Themes/" + Page.Theme + "/icons/16/icon_file.png" %>'
                               NavigateUrl="~/BrandMgmt/BrandMgmtPublicKey.aspx?"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="itemFieldStyle" HeaderStyle-CssClass="headerFieldStyle">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="lnkEdit" ImageUrl='<%# "~/App_Themes/" + Page.Theme + "/icons/16/icon_edit.png" %>'
                               NavigateUrl="~/BrandMgmt/BrandMgmtPublicKey.aspx?"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="itemFieldStyle" HeaderStyle-CssClass="headerFieldStyle">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="cmdDelete" Width="16" Height="16" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "~/App_Themes/" + Page.Theme + "/icons/16/icon_delete.png" %>'
                                 CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("SafetyKeyId") %>' OnCommand="OnDelete"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="KeyOwnerIdentifier" HeaderText="KeyOwnerIdentifier" meta:resourcekey="ColumnKeyOwnerIdentifier"
                        ItemStyle-CssClass="itemFieldStyle" HeaderStyle-CssClass="headerFieldStyle" SortExpression="KeyOwnerIdentifier"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SafetyKeyName" HeaderText="SafetyKeyName" meta:resourcekey="ColumnSafetyKeyName"
                        ItemStyle-CssClass="itemFieldStyle" HeaderStyle-CssClass="headerFieldStyle" SortExpression="SafetyKeyName"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SafetyKeyTypeId" HeaderText="SafetyKeyTypeId" meta:resourcekey="ColumnSafetyKeyTypeId"
                        ItemStyle-CssClass="itemFieldStyle" HeaderStyle-CssClass="headerFieldStyle" SortExpression="SafetyKeyTypeId"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="KeyIndex" HeaderText="KeyIndex" meta:resourcekey="ColumnKeyIndex"
                        ItemStyle-CssClass="itemFieldStyle" HeaderStyle-CssClass="headerFieldStyle" SortExpression="KeyIndex"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FromDate" HeaderText="FromDate" meta:resourcekey="ColumnFromDate"
                        ItemStyle-CssClass="itemFieldStyle" HeaderStyle-CssClass="headerFieldStyle" SortExpression="FromDate"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ToDate" HeaderText="ToDate" meta:resourcekey="ColumnToDate"
                        ItemStyle-CssClass="itemFieldStyle" HeaderStyle-CssClass="headerFieldStyle" SortExpression="ToDate"/>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="itemFieldStyle" HeaderStyle-CssClass="headerFieldStyle"
                           meta:resourcekey="ColumnPublicKey" SortExpression="PublicKey">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div style="max-width: 200px; overflow-y: scroll;">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PublicKey") %>'/>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Grid hat 3 ImageButtons for detail view, editing and deleting per row. DetaliView Button adds additional Table with data to the Page. Editing makes this Table editable. If the grid is sorted and any of those buttons is beeing clicked, Page loads and any sorting is lost.

How can I maintain the sort setting in PostBack after clicking any of those buttons?

Comment: As i understand a click triggers a full reload so if (!Page.IsPostBack) does nothing. You can put the gridview in a update panel. So you won't have a full reload. This way your grid won't be reloaded and your sortings won't be lost

Comment: @H.Mikhaeljan, you will still have a full PostBack with an UpdatePanel, but only the html inside the panel get updated through ajax.

Comment: @VDWWD thanx for clearing that up.

Comment: @H.Mikhaeljan, does not really work, that did not change anything.

Comment: @HugoVrana I'm sorry what i suggested before was a wrong solution. A other solution i can tell you is to keep your sorted grid in viewstate or session. And reload it from there.